# In the molecular kinetic theory of gases, why do the magnitudes of the forces for each molecule add directly?

Tags: forces, kinetic-theory

Should there be a decomposition of the vector components to consider the component perpendicular to the wall and then perform a vector addition?

In other words I don't understand why the total force is calculated as just a sum of the magnitudes of the force:

$$ F_{total}=mv_1^2/l +mv_2^2/l +mv_3^2/l ...????$$

where $ l $ is the length of the container and $v$ the speed of each particle moving in one direction (from the book Physical Chemistry, Gilbert Castellan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite unclear, but I suspect the confusion lies in some kind of simplified picture of the kinetic theory where only a horizontal motion of the particles is considered. In a rigorous treatment of the kinetic theory you would have to define a probability distribution function for all possible angular trajectories a particle can take towards the wall and then integrate out the probability of seeing a particle with a particular speed (Maxwell-Boltzmann) and angle (your angular function) collide with the wall. This is also typically done by considering collisions in some particular small area element over some small time interval. From the elastic change in momentum of the particle over the short time interval and the number density of the particle of gas, you can then get the force applied, which then gives the pressure applied by dividing by the small area element, on the wall due to the collisions from the particles. The mathematical details of this derivation are a bit hairy, but I am willing to elaborate explicitly if desired.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I would be grateful if you can enlighten me on the rigorous mathematical aspects of this theory. I am basing this on Gilbert Castellan's book on physical chemistry, where the model is simplified to particles moving in a single direction. Based on the above, I do not understand why the total force is equal to the sum of the individual forces for each particle.

Comment: That is just the definition of how vectorial quantities add! If I have two forces being applied on an object (think of two people pushing a crate from opposite sides) then the total force is just the vector sum of the forces acting on the object. Since the two people pushing in this silly example are pushing oppositely, their vector components cancel out and only the net difference between their forces (if any) will act on the crate in the direction of the stronger person. The same holds for many particles hitting a wall; though the math is a bit harder!

Comment: Ok, I suppose that what the text says is enough, could you recommend another text to go deeper into these matters? Thank you very much in advance for your response and comments, I am closing the question. Thank you so much

Comment: I would look into Callen’s thermodynamics book. I can also give more details if you like. It would just take me a few minutes to format the math.